# Load image without using system.drawing.image

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdfsharp, .net-4.6

I would like to load a image-stream so that it can be converted to a pdf using [PDFsharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/).

The following code is working in my test/console-application, but not in my project running with ASP.NET Framework 4.6.1. This is because I am using **System.Drawing.Image**.

> Classes within the System.Drawing.Imaging namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions.

**Source**: [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging(v=vs.100).aspx)

How can we solve this problem? My preference is to have everything in memory.

My working code in the console application:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();
pdfDoc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream(inputStream); // Inputstream as byte[]

Image imgSource = Image.FromStream(MemStream); // This will fail
XImage imgX = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(imgSource);

XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfDoc.Pages[0]);
xgr.DrawImage(imgX, 0, 0);

MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
pdfDoc.Save(outputStream, false);
byte[] dataConverted = outputStream.ToArray();
pdfDoc.Close();

return dataConverted;
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to let pdfSharp handle images directly? http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Images-sample.ashx

Comment: Correct, but it accepts only an image-path. And that is exactly what I would like to avoid.
EDIT: And it uses MigraDoc, this is for creating a pdf with images / text / lines / paragraphs etcetera. I'm using pdfSharp for only converting image to pdf directly (http://www.pdfsharp.net/Overview.ashx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the stream to PDFsharp:

```
public static XImage FromStream(Stream stream)
```

With PDFsharp 1.50 this method is public. I think it was not public with version 1.3x.

Use the WPF build of PDFsharp - the GDI build uses `Image.FromStream` internally.

Comment: I had indeed version 1.3x from NuGet.org. When you select "Include Prerelease" you can see the 1.50 versions and also the GDI / WPF packages. Thanks!